# Symfony Sonata SortableBehaviorBundle other DB connection

Tags: database, symfony, sorting, sonata-admin

I have successfully installed the SortableBehaviorBundle in the Sonata-Admin. Now i'm not using only the default DB-connection, but some different for different bundles.
in config.yml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: mysql
      connections:
        mysql:
          driver:         "%mysql_database_driver%"
          ...
        geobundle:
          driver:         "%geo_database_driver%"
        ...
```

in vendor/pixassociates/sortable-behavior-bundle/Pix/SortableBehaviorBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
there ist the definition of

```
  ...
    arguments:
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

if I change this to

```
        - "@doctrine.orm.geobundle_entity_manager"
```

I get the sorted data from my geobundle-DB. If I try to override the setting by my own app/config/services.yml, I get a:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
>   "Macrocom\GeoAdminBundle\Entity\AppAccessServiceprovider". Did you
>   mean to call e.g. "getAppAccess", "getConfig", "getCreatedAt",
>   "getId", "getIsActive", "getPosition", "getServiceprovider" or
>   "getUpdatedAt"?

but when I leave this on original setting I get

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   class 'ACME\GeoAdminBundle\Entity\AppAccessServiceprovider' was
>   not found in the chain configured namespaces
>   ACME\ApiBundle\Entity, ACME\CrmSyncBundle\Entity").

witch seems to try to access the mysql-DB and namespace.
As I dont wat to change the SortableBehaviorBundle everytime I deploy or update teh project to the server, is there a way to override the default-DB for this bundle only.

Best regards
RJ